# Simplest way to add Soap Envelope into a message in WSO2 AM?

Tags: soap, wso2-api-manager

I've been trying something like this:

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
<format>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>$1</soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
</format>
<args>
    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="???"/>
</args>
</payloadFactory>
```

The question is what should I place in the `args` expression to catch the original incoming payload to placed inside the Soap Envelope?

Is this a wrong approach to add the envelope?

Answer (score 0):

you can use synapse xpath variable $body[1] to get the body of incoming message.
[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Synapse+XPath+Variables#SynapseXPathVariables-$body